# Checking the result of repost in php

Tags: php, social-networking

I have a site where there a link of reposts to different social networking sites, like this

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<? echo urlencode("op dop pop"); ?>" target='_blank'>
```

After person click it he get form of repost with my message and I give him a bonus in my site. The problem is that person can decline a repost and still get bonus. Is it possible to control it somehow?
I repost it like this: `twttr.events.bind('tweet', call_soc);`

Comment: It's a good question. Challenging. What is the bonus? Because you don't control the other sites, facebook, twitter etc, user can share, use their bonus with you, then remove share. It's going to be a business decision on accepting the risk and going ahead with the bonus scheme or not. (That said, it's early, wait to see what others come up with). +1 for the question though :-)

Comment: 30 minutes of asterisk call time is my bonus.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution on this?

Comment: Nope, only for facebook and vkontakte. They have api for it.

Comment: The only other thing I thought of was some sort of screen scrape (if the twitter api can't) to look if it actually was done at some point later. Messy though.

Answer (score 0):

Hide/remove using jQuery or css decline btn/link. Some thing like this.

```
$(selector).remove();
```

or

```
selector{display: none;}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how can it help me.

Answer (score 0):

problem is person can decline so hide decline button. Inspect the form and find decline button selector like class/id then use it to hide decline button. 
consider decline button class is " twitter_dec ".
put `.twitter_dec{display: none;}` in your stylesheet.
 Thanks

Comment: The problem is that person can just close a window with tweet. Is it impossible to controll it?